# Wordpress dynamic widget content

Tags: wordpress, dynamic, widget

Is there any way to make the sidebar widget of wordpress to be dynamic? like for example, i would have a twitter widget and it will accept some variables like [ page ] or [ tags ] that will be all different according to the page.

Answer (score 1):

This question is on the one hand too broad and on the other too narrow . To really answer your question a simple "yes" would do . Please try to put some actual code or actual question next time .

Having said that :

Yes, It is <strike>possible</strike> very Easy to do in the widget code using the [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) of wordpress.

Actually, This is the nature of the widgets - to be dynamic and easily customizable .

All you have to do is set your condition on the widget code ( `function widget()` inside the widget class ).

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
 $output = 'x';  // content only for front page
} else if ( is_single( array( 17, 19, 1, 11 ) ) ) {
 $output = 'y'; // content only ID 17,19,1,11
} else {
 $output = 'z'; // content only for all the rest not stated above 
}
```

Refer to the codex page [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets) for general and and to the [widgets API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API)

**EDIT I** after comment

It is up to you to decide which condition mechanism to use . The logic is still exactly the same . may it be `if/else`, `switch` , `ternary` or whatever. If you think about it - what you describe in words in your question, is a 'condition'. in computer logic ( and php ) it is done with conditional statements . and wordpress provides you with an easy mechanism for that . all you have to do is change the `$output` for whatever you want. tweets about `cats`, `dogs`, `salmon fishes` ,`carrots` or `raspberry pie` are exactly the same and you can filter them as such using the page slug for example .

But you will still need conditions. ( also filtering by page slug is a type of condition )

How to do that exactly will depend a lot on what mechanism you use in the specific case to retrieve tweets. Which brings me to my first point of you not posting any details or code .

Comment: Hi, i am actually thinking more dynamic than having an if/else condition around it. 

the main concept is when a user goes to the blog post for example "about cats" the sidebar "twitter_widget" will dynamically show twitter searches for "cats" and same with "about dogs" posts and so on.